# Android NavigationView Listener open/close Activity

Tags: java, android, listener

I got the same NavigationView on several activities and therefore I want to have an own class implementing the Listener for this NavigationView instead of having the same Code in every single Activity.

So I got this class:

```
public class NavigationViewListener implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_my_profile) {

            // Open new Activity here
        }
    }
}
```

But I got no Context or something to open a new Activity/close the one from which this NavigationItem Event was triggered.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways are there 
1. Pass context to that NavigationViewListener using constructor parameter

```
//add these lines to your NavigationViewListener 
private Context context;

public NavigationViewListener(Context context){
     this.context=context;
}
```

from activity pass context like this 
`new NavigationViewListener(YourActivity.this)`

**2.** Use interface to talk to activity.